# Перетаскивание элемента DOM средствами чистого JavaScript

Tags: dom, javascript, pure_js

Всем здравствуйте.

Мне на форуме дали код перетаскивания обьекта по странице вот он:

```
this.e.onmousedown = function (o, el) {
    return function () {
        o.moveX = window.event.clientX;
        o.moveY = window.event.clientY;
        o.elX = parseInt(el.style.left);
        o.elY = parseInt(el.style.top);
        o.move = 1;
    }
}(this, this.e);
this.e.onmouseup = function (o) {
    return function () {
        o.move = 0;
    }
}(this);
this.e.onmouseout = function (o) {
    return function () {
        o.move = 0;
    }
}(this);
this.e.onmousemove = function (o, el) {
    return function () {
        if (o.move == 1) {
            el.style.left = o.elX + (window.event.clientX || window.event.pageX) - o.moveX + 'px';
            el.style.top = o.elY + (window.event.clientY || window.event.pageY) - o.moveY + 'px';
        }
    }
}(this, this.e);
```

А вот html разметка

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Перетаскивание DIV`а</title>
        <style>
            div {
                height: 50px;
                width: 250px;
                background: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Просто DIV</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

У меня проблема с интеграцией кода в разметку, помогите.

Comment: А ссылку на страницу форума на которой это обсуждалось дадите?

Comment: Там только код и все. Или вам код знаком???

Comment: Я не прошу сделать, за меня, я прошу помочь

Comment: Да ну? *"У меня проблема с интегрцией кода в разметку"* и где-же здесь описание того, что именно у вас не получается?

Для меня вопрос выглядит так - мне дали код, вот разметка, работай ХК :)

Comment: Я тут уже 15мн отлаживаю... Вывод: код не кроссбраузерный, его разработчик криворукий, чем полностью переписывать этот код (только так его можно довести до ума) настоятельно рекомендую почитать статью приведённую мною по ссылке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот нормальная статья с готовым кодом: [drag and drop](http://javascript.ru/ui/draganddrop).

Comment: В нем много кода, я прошу помочь уже с имеющимся.

Comment: @Deert настоятельно рекомендую почитать эту статью (и принять мой ответ) ибо ваш "код" никто отлаживать (кроме меня) даже отлаживать не будет

Comment: Ну тут много добрых людей, и из них найдеться кто мне поможет